# How to open InstallShield Limited Edition project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, installshield-le

I have a Visual Studio solution developed in VS 2013. The solution included a setup project bu InstalledShield Limited Edition. Visual Studio 2015 says the setup project is not compatible. I reinstalled InstallShield which didn't didn't help. I don't see anything on Flexera's site about InstallShield which works in VS 2015. Are there plans for one or does Microsoft now want us to use something else for installation projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could theoretically register the extension manually, as in our initial testing that's the minimum required to get ISLE 2013 up and running, we have now released [ISLE 2015](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio), so you should update. This release includes support for Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, .NET 4.6 (including a fix for the 1001 error from installing .NET 4.6), and other enhancements and bug fixes since the 2013 release.

Comment: Any update on timing, now that Windows 10 has been released?  Would be great if InstallShield could update their own site with this information...

Comment: As it happens, yes: we just released InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2015 today.

Comment: @MichaelUrman Ah but ... it won't install if you have VS 2015 Community, although Microsoft says it should work with all VS 2015 apart from Express

Comment: @MichaelUrman I just converted my ISLE 2013 project to ISLE 2015, but now the project won't load in VS2015 :-S

Comment: Ah, good to know ISLE is just as terribly supported as all the other ones.

Comment: I had space limitations on my disk and due to which I uninstalled visual studio 2013 and opted to keep having VS2015 Community installed, now it says its not supported in the community version which is really very sad.